# Create mulitple charts for each row using VBA Macros in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, charts

This is my Excel sheet of name and monthly weight on "sheet2":

[image]

and I have tried following code:

```
Sub BMI()
     'variable declaration
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim ch As Chart
        Dim trend As Trendline
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = ws.Range("$A$3:$N$3")

    For i = 0 To 1
    With ws

        Set ch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        ch.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        ch.SetSourceData Source:=Range(.Name & "!" & rng.Offset(i, 0).Address)
        Set trend = ch.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add(xlLinear)
            With trend.Border
                .ColorIndex = 33
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
            End With
        'Left & top are used to adjust the position of chart on sheet


        ch.ChartArea.Width = 500
        ch.ChartArea.Height = 300
        ch.ChartArea.Left = 200
        ch.ChartArea.Top = (i) * ch.ChartArea.Height + (50 * (i + 1))
    End With

   With ws
         ' Belllow code just to  Add a title.
        ch.HasTitle = True
        With ch.ChartTitle
            .Text = ws.Range("A3").Offset(i, 0)

            ' Set the orientation of the title.
            ' Horizontal is the default, but you can change it
            ' to something else.
            .Orientation = XlOrientation.xlHorizontal

            ' You can format individual characters, or
            ' the entire title:
            With .Characters(1, 1).Font
                .Size = 24
                .Color = rgbDarkBlue

            End With

            .Characters(2).Font.Size = 14

            With .Format

                .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
                With .Shadow
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
                    .Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
                    .OffsetX = 4
                    .OffsetY = 4
                End With
            End With

            ' Make sure and leave room for the title in the chart.
            .IncludeInLayout = True
        End With
    End With
     ' code just to  Add a title finish.


    Set ch = Nothing
    Set trend = Nothing

Next

Set rng = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

Problem:

1. It's creating chart like below:-

[image]

I want to Legend series names as January, February...

2. trendline now showing up.

Answer (score 0):

After long research I found the answer.
POsting here, may be useful for someone.
Working code :-

```
  Sub Weight_charts()

   'variable declaration
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim trend As Trendline
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Name & "!" & "$A$2," & ws.Name & "!" & "$D$2:$O$2")

    For i = 1 To 2
    With ws

        Set ch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weight_charts").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        ch.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

       MsgBox rng.Offset(0, 0).Address & rng.Offset(i, 0).Address

       ch.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range(rng.Offset(0, 0).Address & ", " & rng.Offset(i, 0).Address)
       ch.PlotBy = xlRows       ' very important line to swap column and rows in chart
       ' ch.SetSourceData Source:=Range(.Name & "!" & rng.Offset(i, 0).Address)
        Set trend = ch.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add(xlLinear)
            With trend.Border
                .ColorIndex = 33
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
            End With
        'Left & top are used to adjust the position of chart on sheet


        ch.ChartArea.Width = 500
        ch.ChartArea.Height = 300
        ch.ChartArea.Left = 200
        ch.ChartArea.Top = (i) * ch.ChartArea.Height + (50 * (i + 1))
    End With

   With ws
         ' Belllow code just to  Add a title.
        ch.HasTitle = True
        With ch.ChartTitle
            .Text = ws.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0)

            ' Set the orientation of the title.
            ' Horizontal is the default, but you can change it
            ' to something else.
            .Orientation = XlOrientation.xlHorizontal

            ' You can format individual characters, or
            ' the entire title:
            With .Characters(1, 1).Font
                .Size = 24
                .Color = rgbDarkBlue

            End With

            .Characters(2).Font.Size = 14

            With .Format

                .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
                With .Shadow
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
                    .Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
                    .OffsetX = 4
                    .OffsetY = 4
                End With
            End With

            ' Make sure and leave room for the title in the chart.
            .IncludeInLayout = True
        End With
    End With
     ' code just to  Add a title finish.


    Set ch = Nothing
    Set trend = Nothing

Next

Set rng = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```